# How to develop Android applications?

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I used to be an Android developer for 2 years, but over 2 years ago. I believe that things changed - we have Android Studio, Gradle and probably more tools that I'm not aware of right now.

What is the current development stack for creating Android applications? What tools should we used right now?
I used to use eclipse with ant, but as far as I can see, a lot of people are using AS with Gradle, which is, for my first experience, extremely slow.

How to jump back into Android development after some time of not being up to date with development stack?

Comment: I am also curious about the answers. I tried Android Studio and had the same experience too. It is slow compared to eclipse.

Comment: `we have Android Studio, Gradle and probably more tools that I'm not aware of right now.` And you probably don't need them. **I'm still happy with Eclipse!** `a lot of people are using AS with Gradle` I don't need to **emulate** what other people do. I'm able to reason with my own head.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi are there any changes in your reasoning sir?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse vs Android Studio is a matter of choice. You can get used to it within hours, or you can continue with Eclipse. I am using both tools for different projects.

- Android Studio seemed to be more stabile at some points.
- Update on Android SDK and third party libraries are more easily handled with Android Studio.
- Android Studio has not NDK support yet. You have to compile native codes outside of Android Studio. *Edit:(Well, actually it has support but claimed to be deprecated, probably developers are working on a better solution)* 
  *Edit2:(It will be soon officially supported with C/C++ debugger)*
- With Android Studio you can use java7 syntax, but you have to stick with java6 syntax on Eclipse. *Edit:(you can now force java8 with a plugin on A.S and I guess java7 is usable on eclipse too)* *Edit2:(java7 is a must now for both parties, but still java8 syntax can only be used in A.S with a help of plugin)*
- Google releases example codes compatible with Android Studio saying eclipse versions will be available soon.
- Android Studio has better GUI designer.
- Android Studio has better refactoring capabilities.

The most important change is SDK itself, actually. Just check if Android Studio is good enough for you and study on SDK.

Comment: Has Android Studio the "Analyze -> Dataflow to here" option in the code editor context menu?

Comment: @gorefest Yes it does, but I have not used it yet.

Comment: one of the strongest feature I always miss in eclipse and netbeans btw. Track the setting of a field thru all code related is quite a cool feature and saved my butt several times :D

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your project. For non critical or hobby projects you should definitely start with AS and Gradle right away because this the the future of Android development. Although it is still in 'beta' and it can break some stuff after a new upgrade, it has many new features which make you more productive and happier in development.

If you have a critical project and you don't want to spend your time with checking and fixing things your are not supposed to fix, you should stick back to Eclipse, at least until AS is released.

Independently on whether you use AS or Eclipse, you should already start learning and using Gradle. It works perfectly for both options. If you hesitate you can even keep Ant and Gradle building your project in parallel. They work together and don't overlap.

Answer (score 2):

My development stack for Android :

- IntelliJ 14
- Maven
- Android SDK
- plus my own [OSS Framework to ease the pain of Android](http://www.baracus.org) for a Java EE developer

Reasons:

- IntelliJ is the best available IDE imo
- Maven is pretty mature
- The plugin has become useable
- The workspace integration Maven -> IntelliJ is working great (both, using maven builds and deriving IDE builds from maven)

If Android Studio (which is in great parts IntelliJ) has become slow, it come due to the gradle stuff. I had a large scale project based on gradle and made these experiences :

- Slow, Slower, gradle (up to 2GB memor consumption for building an app)
- Xml is horrible, but gradle dsl is imo even worse
- Switching to gradle 2.1 broke the predicate logic (e.g. formerly working project.hasProperty("foo") && property.ext.foo.equals("bar") does not work any more, this must not happen during a MINOR release

Compared with maven's xml hell, gradle leaves a callow, unmature impression on me, especially building with gradle is hell of a slow job compared with maven.

But - and this is my true oppionion - if gradle is pushed by google and gradleware, it definitely has the potential to become the next generation building tool, although I doubt that the flexibility in gradle will ever lead to a proper IDE workspace build derivation. From my point of view, the choice for gradle over maven done by google happened in a too early state.

just my two cents.

PS: Try tuning the memory settings. Give more memory to IDEA (e.g. 2GB in a 64bit enviroment). My experience with IntelliJ is, that the default mem settings are too small. You can find it in $InstallDir/bin/idea.exe.vmoptions resp. $InstallDir/bin/idea64.exe.vmoptions

EDIT: This is not intended to be gradle bashing. Gradle has large potentials indeed. This post reflects my experiences during my last project basing on gradle (non-Android). For beginners gradle might be the better choice since it is a lot easier than maven.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Android Studio the last year and I can say that it is a very powerful tool, that I believe, in the next year, will overcome Eclipse.

When AS was still in version 4.+ Alpha, there were some issues (mostly with external libraries .jar) but since beta was released and up until now almost every bug was fixed.

Moreover, AS is better when it comes to indexing and suggestions. You will be surprised by its suggestion system, which helps you save a lot of time when coding.

I still use eclipse for other projects, but I believe for Android Development AS is the tool you should invest in, if not for now, definitely for the future.

Answer (score 2):

We are using both, Android Studio and the good old Eclipse IDE. We noticed, that it basically depends on what you're doing. Android Studio is good enough for developing from now and it will replace Eclipse soon. However, it has some drawbacks where Eclipse is your choice. A small comparison was made by Google themselves: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

**Eclipse**: Eclipse is very stable and works perfectly with ant driven builds. However, if you want to use gradle, there's some work to do to get the build process working with eclipse. We tried to use Eclipse with Gradle but the Gradle Plugin was quite buggy at this time. If you want to use native C code, you must use Eclipse, as Android Studio does not support that, yet.

**Android Studio**: Looks great and does also a very good job. The gradle integration works much better there. This is a big advantage over Eclipse when you have to deal with many dependencies. This is probably not an issue for small projects. But, if you're developing projects with additional libraries or frameworks you should definitely give Gradle a try. I hope, that the NDK support is coming soon, so that we can switch to AS completely. Ant builds are someway out-dated.

Answer (score 2):

*First of all, I will not debate about Android Studio vs Eclipse as it's an opinion based discussion and a kind of a troll...*

The Android development basically the same : the base tools still ADB, Android SDK, Java language... So you can continue to use a "notepad" and compile, build and deploy by the SDK tools.

However, like in every development project, you could choose your upper level tools. Your question is about IDE and building system. This is **only** a matter of choice.

Android Studio and Gradle are still in beta phase for Android developments and you could use them only if you keep this in mind. You could continue to use Eclipse and Maven or switch to Android Studio and Gradle or keep using Eclipse but moving from Maven to Gradle... just make what you prefer.

The Android development stack evolved this way :

- **Basics tools** : Text editor, SDK tools
- **First IDE** : Eclipse with ADT plugin (can run your program from an IDE)
- **Industrialisation phase** : Eclipse ADT + Maven (dependencies management, building process management...)
- **Coming phase** : Android Studio (IntelliJ based) + Gradle (you can compare Gradle to Maven, but this is another discussion)

I think that other answers will give you personnal points of view about Eclipse vs Android Studio, Maven vs Gradle, etc... which is a really personnal choice ;)